# Illegal to use fflush() in stdin? What to do instead?

Tags: c, stdin, fflush

```
char c;
char s[32];
puts("Type a char");
c=getchar();
fflush(stdin);
puts("Type a string");
fgets(s,32,stdin);
```

Without the fflush(), if you type a character, say "a", and the hit enter, the input buffer contains "a\n", the getchar() peeks the "a", but the "\n" remains in the buffer, so the next fgets() will find it and return an empty string without even waiting for user input.

What should be done instead? As far as i know, it's not defined or standard to use fflush() on an input stream?

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `getchar` when your intent is to read a line of input and interpret one character from it. In this case, read a line with `fgets` or similar and just inspect the first line.

Alternatively, you can stick with `getchar`, but then you need to keep reading characters until the end of the line and throw them away before moving on.

Your program could be transformed to (first approach):

```
char c;
char s[32];
puts("Type a char");
fgets(s,32,stdin);
c=s[0];
puts("Type a string");
fgets(s,32,stdin);
```

Note that this is missing checking of return values and doesn't handle input longer than 32 bytes, but it's a start and those are separate issues you can work on.

Comment: Okej thanks, but what should be done in this example:

´ printf("hp: ");
 scanf("%f",&acourse.hp);
 fflush(stdin);
 printf("Grade: ");
 scanf("%c",&acourse.grade);´

Comment: In the case of `scanf` where you want to read a whole line but just interpret one field from it, something like this works: `scanf("%f%*[^\n]%*c", &x);` Alternatively (most people prefer the latter), use `fgets` then `sscanf` rather than using `scanf`.

Comment: @Xisso2 note `fflush(stdin);` does not apply to **input** streams. It will return `EBADF` error and not do what you think it does. See `man 3 fflush`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `fflush` on an input stream results in undefined behavior, not a diagnosable error. POSIX fills in this gap and defines the behavior for seekable input streams, but not non-seekable ones, which are still left undefined.

Comment: I see the distinction, `EBADF` can tell you that its failure was due to being run on a stream not for writing, but being run on stdin will not necessarily set `EBADF`. Thanks for pointing out the difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to discard the rest of the input line, then do this:

```
int ch;
while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) { }
```

This reads characters until there are no more, or it hits the end of the line.

Note that you should be using `int c;` rather than `char c;` . The `getchar()` function actually does not return a `char` value; it returns the result of converting that char to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html); you probably want to call `fflush(NULL);`*before* `c=getchar();` but that might not work as you want.

Remember that on Linux at least the terminal is often kernel buffered (and also *stdio* buffered). Read more about [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)-s. So you often won't get any input till the user pressed the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

You should rethink your program and read entire lines (often with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) on a large enough buffer).

If you want to get individual key presses on Linux (or other POSIX systems) you need a library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) (which works with the terminal in raw mode). You might be interested in [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)